# Cannot find UV Mapping options on tools shelf

Tags: uv

I'm a programmer and making graphics is something very difficult for me, but for one project I need to apply a panoramic image to the inner side of a semi sphere. 
So I found this tutorial on how to unwrap the sphere https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yc0b5GcYl3U
it all went fine up to the part where he uses sphere projection. Look at the time 2:20+. He's got the UV Mapping (Direction, Aling) on the toos shelf. But there is nothing like that in my blender setup (2.73). Just look at my screenshot
[image]

Where can I find those options? Or how can I unwrap this semisphere to something like a rectangle like the guy does on the video?

Comment: There wasn't an answer to my question. The answer is here. The problem was that it appears after event only

Comment: The two questions marked here as a duplicate answer do not actually answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options you see on the tool shelf in the bottom left (which is what I think you are referring to) appear **after** you have performed the unwrap operation. It is sometimes called the operator panel.

You can also access it by pressing `F6` after your perform any operation.

It is a bit counter-intuitive, but a lot of operations in Blender come with options to change the effect after the event. These appear in the operator panel, and have retrospective effect. Those options are no longer available when you switch to a different tool or start another operation.

Comment: Wow! This really worked after the event. It almost blew up my mind, lol.. Thank you very much. Sorry, I have to right to upvote your answer because of zero reputation. But it really helped :)

Comment: @user1512726 No problem, great to hear you have it resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You will see the options, you're referring to also, when You click on the little + sign visible on your image on the left ,right next to "History"

Comment: Yep, I tried it, but I didn't know that I have to do the unwrap after I do it. That's why I couldn't see anything there